# How to dynamically replay the image source for an image button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I have an image button with the following xml:

```
    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:contentDescription="@string/button_click1"
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_margin="20dp"
      android:src="@drawable/button_default" />
```

Now I want to dynamically change the image source from loading a file. I know the right way is to use

```
 this.button.setImageDrawable(this.default_source);
```

The problem is I want to make sure two things:
1. The new image should be in the same place as before replacing. 
2. If the newly loaded image is not 200dp * 100dp, I want automatically scale the 
image not cutting it. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following xml attribute into your `ImageButton` xml...

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

as below...

```
<ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:contentDescription="@string/button_click1"
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_margin="20dp"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:src="@drawable/button_default" />
```